# Can you run out of storage space while running a blockchain node?

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency

Maybe a dumb question, and perhaps not one for stack overflow, but from what I understand running a full node requires locally storing the entire ledger for the network you're running. Correct? What happens if the size of the ledger increases beyond a users storage size though?

For example, if a user has 10gb of storage space, and the size of the ledger exceeds beyond 10gb? Does that node just die? Is the circulating supply in place to solve this problem? How about for networks with infinite supply

Answer (score 1):

You get an insufficient disk space error and the node cannot keep the ledger up to date and will fall behind. Depending on the implementation in your node, the policies of the chain, etc. different things can happen. In some staking chains, your node may be considered to be unable to validate new transactions and be unreliable. This can eat in to your staked value depending on what the policies are.

Circulating supply doesn't mean much to storage, but length of history, contained data, ability to prune, etc. all have large effects. For instance, you can run a full BSV node, but aggressively prune it while still being able to validate the chain. The reason why this is important is because the block size limits being removed leaves node operators with an untenable cost. Ripple's full history was over 14 Tb recently, and isn't a recommended thing to do for anyone, even enterprise.